# copy database structure without data in sybase 15.5 (with empty tables)

Tags: sql, sybase-ase15

Is there any way to copy database structure without data in Sybase using ddlgen utility, so the new database will be the same as it is copied from, but with empty tables.

Answer (score 0):

The ddlgen tool by default only generates the SQL for a given database object so that you can run that SQL to re-create the object either to re-create the object or create it elsewhere. It will not migrate the data you would need to use bcp or perhaps sybmigrate to do the data copy.